# postfix with dovecot : many authentication failures

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have installed postfix with dovecot and after while i have found tons of authentication failures from internet. I have installed and configured fail2ban and every not authenticated IP is banned but maybe there is other solution or maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Log example:

```
Mar  8 08:48:01 somehostname auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=news rhost=45.88.90.208  user=news
```

Is there any other solutions to disable login/connection for clients from internet and enable only from local net ? - there is no need to retrieve emails from internet for clients in my case. Maybe there is other solution ?

Dovecot sample configuration in postfix main.cf:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

Thank you in advance
AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable SASL authentication on SMTP port `25` altogether, as authenticated users should be using *submissions* a.k.a. *Implicit TLS for SMTP Submission* ([RFC 8314, 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314.html#section-3.3)), instead.

- In `main.cf`: `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no` (default)
- Override the SASL authentication related settings in `master.cf` for `smptd` instance `smtps`/`465`, e.g.,

  ```
  smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o { smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
             reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
             reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
             permit_sasl_authenticated,
             reject
       }
  ```

After that you could limit the port `465` for local networks in a firewall.

Comment: Thnx for a hint

Answer (score 0):

You may restrict imap ports 143,465,587,993  with iptables to LAN only.

Comment: Connections from Internet to port 25 ( other ports then 25/tcp from internet are blocked ) are forwarded by postfix to dovecot to authenticate so i don't think it will work.